# Automatically remove source files after collectstatic with django-pipeline

Tags: django, django-pipeline, collectstatic

With django-pipeline, is it possible to automatically remove source files after collectstatic ?

for example :

```
PIPELINE_JS = {
    'stats': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'js/jquery.js',
          'js/d3.js',
          'js/application.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/stats.js',
    }
}
```

collectstatic :

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
$ ls static/js
jquery.js
d3.js
application.js
stats.js
```

(i don't want jquery.js, d3.js, application.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-pipeline sends signals whenever it compiles package, you can read more about this in [docs](https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html), and about signals in general [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/). You can hook this signal like this:

```
from pipeline.signals import js_compressed

def clear_files(sender, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    if 'package' in kwargs:
        print kwargs['package'].sources
        # here remove unwanted files

js_compressed.connect(clear_files)
```

Comment: i wrote that in "models.py". it works, but is it appropriate to write that in "models.py" ?

Comment: It works, but it's so ugly. Why doesn't pipeline offer a way to not publish the source files along the compiled version? :(

Comment: I don't think it's ugly. It's just hooking to an event dispatched by library. Replacing some core protected function or mocking whole class would be ugly ;)